# harmonic functions: comparison of gradients

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Consider $\Omega$ a open, bounded, convex domain in $R^n.$

I am trying to justify this:

Let $u, v$ non negative harmonic functions in $\Omega$ (in the Sobolev sense). Suppose that $ u = v =0$ in some neighbourhood of $x \in \partial \Omega$ and $u \geq v$ in $\Omega.$ Then

$$ lim \ sup_{y \rightarrow x} |\nabla u(y)| \geq lim \ sup_{y \rightarrow x} |\nabla v(y)| .$$

In the remark 1 of this paper:

http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/12/87/60/PDF/fbpLaplacian.pdf

The authors say that the clam is true. I really dont understand the justificative of the paper.

Someone could explain to me please (or give a reference different of the article with a proof)?

Any help will be appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Let $B(x,r)$ be a ball such that $u=v=0$ in $B(x,r)\cap \Omega$. Then $\nabla u=\nabla v=0$ in $B(x,r)\cap \Omega$.

Comment: Probably it mean a neighbourhood in the topology of $\partial\Omega$?

Comment: I read the paper (not in full details) and I believe the possibilities are: i) what you said in your last comentary ii) u(x) = v(x) only (and not in a neighbourhood of x)

Comment: You omitted the assumption that $u$ and $v$ are nonnegative. Also, I think the authors meant to say that $u(y)\to 0$ and $v(y)\to 0$ as $y\to x$. The assumption does not make much sense otherwise.

Comment: Also, what part are you unhappy with: proof of Lemma 1, or derivation of Remark 1 from Lemma 1?

Comment: I believe that you're right. Well i am unhappy with the remark. if you know a proof for it please post, it will help me a lot =D .  I am in troble with the proof of the lemma 1, but i will stay thinking about this lemma. (my english is not good, sorry =\)

Comment: about the non negativity, you're right. I forget. sorry! I will fix it

Comment: Other thing that I believe: we have to suppose that what you writed and $u(x) = v(x)$.